# Append a new list from a for loops returned elements

Tags: python, python-3.x, append

Having an issue appending gamepk to a new list to then set and remove duplicates. My first issue is just making a new list. I can worry about the set later.

```
import csv
import requests
import datetime
from pprint import pprint
import pendulum

start = pendulum.datetime(2016, 4, 3)
end = pendulum.datetime(2016, 10, 2)
period = pendulum.period(start, end)

for dt in period.range('days'):
    day = dt.format('DD')
    month = dt.format('MM')
    year = dt.format('YYYY')
    the_date = str(month) + "/" + str(day) + "/" + str(year)

    try:
        req = requests.get('http://gd.mlb.com/components/game/mlb/year_' + str(year) + '/month_' + str(month) + '/day_' + str(day) + '/miniscoreboard.json') # 
        get_gameIds = req.json()['data']['games']['game']

        for gameId in get_gameIds:
            gamepk = gameId['game_pk']
            new_gamepk = []
            for pk in gamepk:                
                new_gamepk.append(pk)
                print(new_gamepk)
```

Printing gamepk after the second to last for loop results in a list like this:

```
446877
452866
446911
446873
446870
446875
446872
446876
446867
446874
446879
446871
```

I feel like its there that I should store the gamepk results as a list.. but im not sure. What I am trying to do is then append all of those gamepks to a new list which I can then call `set` on and remove the duplicates. I understand the concept of append but clearly cant seem to get it to work properly. Any help and brief explanation goes a long way!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea in general is to:

- Initialize an empty collection (list, set) outside of the outermost loop
- Once you've found the item you want, add it to the collection.

**Using a list**

```
import csv
import requests
import datetime
from pprint import pprint
import pendulum

start = pendulum.datetime(2016, 4, 3)
end = pendulum.datetime(2016, 10, 2)
period = pendulum.period(start, end)

gamepks = []
for dt in period.range('days'):
    day = dt.format('DD')
    month = dt.format('MM')
    year = dt.format('YYYY')
    the_date = str(month) + "/" + str(day) + "/" + str(year)

    try:
        req = requests.get('http://gd.mlb.com/components/game/mlb/year_' + str(year) + '/month_' + str(month) + '/day_' + str(day) + '/miniscoreboard.json') # 
        get_gameIds = req.json()['data']['games']['game']

        for gameId in get_gameIds:
            gamepk = gameId['game_pk']
            gamepks.append(gamepk)
```

**Using a set**

```
import csv
import requests
import datetime
from pprint import pprint
import pendulum

start = pendulum.datetime(2016, 4, 3)
end = pendulum.datetime(2016, 10, 2)
period = pendulum.period(start, end)

gamepks = set()
for dt in period.range('days'):
    day = dt.format('DD')
    month = dt.format('MM')
    year = dt.format('YYYY')
    the_date = str(month) + "/" + str(day) + "/" + str(year)

    try:
        req = requests.get('http://gd.mlb.com/components/game/mlb/year_' + str(year) + '/month_' + str(month) + '/day_' + str(day) + '/miniscoreboard.json') # 
        get_gameIds = req.json()['data']['games']['game']

        for gameId in get_gameIds:
            gamepk = gameId['game_pk']
            gamepks.add(gamepk)
```

It's important to understand scoping.  Variables declared inside of inner scopes (e.g. inside of for loops) "disappear" once the loop exits.  That may help guide you regarding where you should initialize the variables (in this case the list/set) that you want to persist after the loop ends.

Comment: Thanks @jedwards! In this example how do I go on with the script using gamepks. e.g. how to print it or pass it into another request? When I try and print it out I get unexpected indent and invalid syntax?

Comment: Those two errors seem like a side effect of trying to copy/paste.  I'd just take the code you had and add a gamepks = <whatever you choose> above the first for loop and manually add the `.append` or `.add` calls.

Comment: You're right, forgot the try: part. Using the set method automatically takes all duplicates out right? Thanks Again!

Comment: Yep, `set.add()` will let you add in duplicates (as in not throw an error) but it will silently ignore them.

Comment: perfect. I apologize to keep asking questions but should i now right a for loop to extract these back out into single strings to pass into a new url request?

Comment: It's hard to say, but if that's what you want to do :) You can certainly iterate over the set once you've finished populating it (e.g. `for gamepk in gamepks: ...`)

Comment: speed wise does that make sense? The purpose of this is to go through all games in the season, get the game_ids(gamepks) but remove the duplicates.. not sure why there are but there is. Then use those individual not duplicate gamepks strings to pass 1 by 1 into a url to return more data per game..

Comment: Yep, I'd say your approach seems fine.

Comment: Last question I’m trying to sort the set. So when I write my for loop to access it it’s in smallest to largest. Because right now it’s all over the place..

Comment: If you only need the sorted set values once (to iterate over in your for loop) something like `for gamepk in sorted(gamepks):` should work.